# Browser autofill registration form in React.js and validate field values

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I have added validations on OnBlur event. and I am disabling Submit button if validation flag comes with false.
So I am not getting that,how to catch browser autofill values at a time and validate it.

Like I want to validate firstName and LastName fields value at a time.so I can get validation flag to validate fields.
Below I am adding snippet of my code : -

```
    setInputStateOnValidation: function(inputAttrs) {
    //validation checking method
    var validateData = this.getValidationData(inputAttrs);
    this[inputAttrs.rules.validFlag] = this.validateInput(validateData);
    var allStates = this.state;
    allStates[inputAttrs.rules.inputClass] = this.getClassSet({
        'form-group': true,
        'errmsgActive': !this[inputAttrs.rules.validFlag]
    });
    this.setState(allStates);
    this.params[inputAttrs.rules.paramField] = (inputAttrs.data && inputAttrs.data.toString().length) ? inputAttrs.data : '';
    this.validateAll();
},

validateInputValues: function(fieldName, value, validationMsg) {
   // onBlur of every field this method will be called 
    this[validationMsg] = [];
    var value = fieldName == 'phoneNumber' ? this.contactNumberMask(value) : value;
    var inputAttrs = this.validator(fieldName, value);
    this.setInputStateOnValidation(inputAttrs);
},
render: function() {
    var addressSignUpClass = true;
    return (
         <div className="clearfix">
          <UserInputView label="First Name" fieldName = {'firstName'}  placeholder="Enter First Name" required={true} inputClass="form-control" type="text" onBlur={this.validateInputValues} validateMessages={this.firstNameErrors} wrapperClass={this.state.firstNameClass}/>
          <UserInputView label="Last Name" fieldName = {'lastName'} placeholder="Enter Last Name" required={true} inputClass="form-control" type="text"  onBlur={this.validateInputValues} validateMessages={this.lastNameErrors} wrapperClass={this.state.lastNameClass}/>
```

) 
     }

I have written one custom userInputView to minimise common html code .
Now when browser will autofill the values of firstName and LastName I want to validate both of these fiels at a time.

Comment: Can you post your code, pls ?

Comment: I have added my code sample.